# How do I fork an empty repository on github?

Tags: git, github, version-control, repository

It seems the github's web-UI does not allow to use the "Fork" button on empty repositories. I'd like to fork, add files, make a commit and then a pull request on somebody else's completely empty repository. Is there a workaround, or should I just wait until he adds a file?

Comment: I don't think there is a workaround. It would be enough if the owner created a LICENSE or README.md but without files you cannot fork in Github.

Comment: Related question, is there a way to create two forks of an existing repo in the same account?

Comment: No, you cannot create a second fork for the same user/org in the sense that Github tracks it as such. You can clone the repository and push it to your Github account under a different name. But it seems that creating a branch would be the sensible thing.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think there is a workaround. It would be enough if the owner created a `LICENSE` or `README.md` but without files you cannot fork in Github.